# ¿Por qué AJAX no lee mi respuesta PHP de manera correcta?

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo un sistema en el que estoy utilizando AJAX para insertar datos,

```
$.ajax({
        data:  formData, //send data via AJAX
        url:   '../controller/serviceController.php', //url file controller PHP
        dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the server
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type:  'post', //send POST data
        beforeSend: function () {
          document.getElementById("load").style.display = "block";
        },
        success:  function (response) { //get request

        var confirm = response.success;

        if(confirm){ 
          $("#successModalTitle").html("<i class='fas fa-check-circle color-success'></i> ¡Success!");
          $("#successModalDescription").html(response.message);
        }else{
          $("#successModalTitle").html("<i class='fas fa-exclamation-circle color-error'></i> ¡Error!");
          $("#successModalDescription").html(response.message);
        }

          //alert(response.message);
          $('#actionModal').modal('toggle');
          $('#services').DataTable().ajax.reload();
          $('.close').click(); 

        }
      });
```

Le mando todos los datos que necesito en mi archivo PHP, voy al archivo PHP, creo variables que voy a utilizar e inserto mis datos, EL QUERY ES CORRECTO porque sí INSERTA,

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
        $cost = $_POST['cost'];
        $desc = $_POST['desc'];
        $id_tipo_servicio = $_POST['id_tipo_servicio'];
        $date = date("Y-m-d");
        $iva = 0;
        $status = 1;

        $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
        //$ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
        $destino = ".../img/" . $nombre;

        require_once 'conn/connection.php';
        $connect = new connection();
        $connection=$connect->connections();


        $sql = "INSERT INTO servicios (id_tipo_servicio, ser_nombre, ser_descripcion, ser_img_url, ser_precio, ser_fecha_creacion, ser_fecha_actualizacion, ser_iva, ser_status) VALUES ('".$id_tipo_servicio ."','".$name."','".$desc."','".$destino."','".$cost."','".$date ."', '".$date."', '".$iva."', '".$status."');";


        $jsondata = array();

        $insert = $connection->query($sql);

        var_dump($insert);

        if ($insert===true) {
            $jsondata['success'] = true;
            $jsondata['message'] = 'Felicidades! Has insertado el Servicio con Éxito.';

        } else {
            $jsondata['success'] = false;
            $jsondata['message'] = 'Error! Ha ocurrido un error, avisa a un administrador.';
        }
        //Aunque el content-type no sea un problema en la mayoría de casos, es recomendable especificarlo
        header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

        echo json_encode($jsondata, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Entonces al tener esto correcto hago un IF, en donde asigno valores al ARRAY que devuelve mi PHP en formato JSON para que lo LEA mi AJAX de vuelta.

```
$insert = $connection->query($sql);

        var_dump($insert);

        if ($insert===true) {
            $jsondata['success'] = true;
            $jsondata['message'] = 'Felicidades! Has insertado el Servicio con Éxito.';

        } else {
            $jsondata['success'] = false;
            $jsondata['message'] = 'Error! Ha ocurrido un error, avisa a un administrador.';
        }
```

Entonces al estar de nuevo en el AJAX, en ves de mostrar los resultados del PHP, muestra mi alerta de error,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero la RESPUESTA ES CORRECTA. El AJAX debió entrar a esta parte del código

```
 var confirm = response.success;
if(confirm){ 
          $("#successModalTitle").html("<i class='fas fa-check-circle color-success'></i> ¡Success!");
          $("#successModalDescription").html(response.message);
        }
```

PERO NO ES ASI. Entra al apartado del ERROR y no me muestra la descripción de la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta que tienes definido `dataType` como `text` y debería ser `json`

ejemplo:

```
$.ajax({
        data:  formData, //send data via AJAX
        url:   '../controller/serviceController.php', //url file controller PHP
        dataType: "json", // what to expect back from the server
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type:  'post', //send POST data
        beforeSend: function () {
          document.getElementById("load").style.display = "block";
        },
        success:  function (response) { //get request

        var confirm = response.success;

        if(confirm){ 
          $("#successModalTitle").html("<i class='fas fa-check-circle color-success'></i> ¡Success!");
          $("#successModalDescription").html(response.message);
        }else{
          $("#successModalTitle").html("<i class='fas fa-exclamation-circle color-error'></i> ¡Error!");
          $("#successModalDescription").html(response.message);
        }

          //alert(response.message);
          $('#actionModal').modal('toggle');
          $('#services').DataTable().ajax.reload();
          $('.close').click(); 

        }
      });
```

Comment: Genial, agradezco mucho tu ayuda!